# Combine array data into one variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have foreaching array:

```
$arr = array(2,3,4);
$copy = $arr;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    echo $val;
    if (next($copy )) {
        echo ','; // Add comma for all elements instead of last
    }
}
```

and the result is:

> 2,3,4

How to create a variable with value is above result, so it will looks like `$var = '2,3,4'` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach ($arr as $val) {
     $copy += $val;
}
```

Comment: if you want to add comma $copy += $val + ",";

Answer (score 1):

Use [implode():](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$arr = [2,3,4];
$var = implode($arr, ',');
var_dump( $var );
```

Output:

> string(5) "2,3,4"